# Solve differential equation by change of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with this exercise.

> Solve the differential equation $$y(2t^{2}\sqrt{y}+2)\,\mathrm dt + t(t^{2}\sqrt y +2) \,\mathrm dy=0$$ using $u = t^{2}\sqrt y$.

My steps:
$$\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} = 2t \sqrt y + t^{2}\frac{1}{2 \sqrt y} y'$$
And $y= \frac{u}{t^2}$ gives
$$y'= \frac{1}{t^2}\times (- \sqrt u + \frac{1}{2 \sqrt u})$$
When I replacement in the equation, the solution is not real number, I  tried this exercise by different forms.

Thanks if you give me the solution.
Also, please I need some recommendations about find interesting books or material with differential equation by change of variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your first step is correct:
$$
\frac{du}{dt}=2t\sqrt{y}+\frac{t^2y'}{2\sqrt{y}}. \tag{1}
$$
Now, let's substitute
$$
y'=-\frac{y(2t^2\sqrt{y}+2)}{t(t^2\sqrt{y}+2)} \tag{2}
$$
in $(1)$:
$$
\frac{du}{dt}=2t\sqrt{y}-\frac{t\sqrt{y}(2t^2\sqrt{y}+2)}{2(t^2\sqrt{y}+2)}. \tag{3}
$$
Substituting $\sqrt{y}=\frac{u}{t^2}$ in $(3)$, we obtain
$$
\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{2u}{t}-\frac{u(2u+2)}{2t(u+2)}=\frac{u(u+3)}{t(u+2)}. \tag{4}
$$
Equation $(4)$ is a separable ODE. You should have no difficulty in solving it.

---

*Remark.* Using the fact that the original differential equation is exact, one can find its solution in a less convoluted way. The result is
$$
\frac{2}{3}t^3y^{3/2}+2ty=C. \tag{5}
$$